# React Native Expo Best Practices for Sharing Code Base & App Experience Virtually

Tags: xcode, expo, collaboration

I am building an app with React Native using Expo and I am trying to collaborate with a third party virtually via Zoom. Ideally I would like that individual to see not just my code base (I can share my screen easily for that purpose) but what the app looks like/functions once i log in. To my understanding, I can use either the Expo app and/or Xcode. The expo app doesn't work here because you need to share the same wifi (at least I believe that's how it works) and Xcode isn't working for me because it takes up so much space locally (I have over 20 gb of free space and it still wont allow me to download). So is there a third option that would solve this problem? Am I overlooking something here? Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @Codebling i very much appreciate you following up on this. please read the comments i posted below.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [guide](https://medium.com/@jamischarles/easily-share-a-react-native-app-during-development-d40ac27af6ef) on how to do what you want to do.

Alternatively, you should be able to share your Expo project with someone by sending them a link, then conference with them using Zoom, if you wish.

Another option would be to use a different IDE, for example VS Code, which has a [live share plugin](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/11/15/live-share)

Comment: unfortunately I dont believe this solution works any longer (publishing a url). When I tried this solution, I was able to scan the QR code and get the app running just fine on my phone, but when someone else tried, they got the following: https://ucarecdn.com/823f5da7-2c5c-4be8-9c2b-07bfca0cfcab/

Comment: it appears from this github post that others seem to agree. perhaps there is some type of workaround? https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2724

Comment: Here is the link to my project if you would like to try https://expo.io/@bullybear/hoodv2

Comment: The GitHub issue you linked has a comment with a link to [this post](https://blog.expo.io/upcoming-limitations-to-ios-expo-client-8076d01aee1a), which says "Rather than a QR code, use the Send Link function in XDE and `exp` to load your project instead". You tried that, as well?

Comment: I have. I get an email with the following link (it's broken). https://expo.io/--/to-exp/exp%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.2%3A19000

Comment: for the record I was able to successfully install xcode and run the simulator from my laptop - however I believe this post should perhaps stay open so that others can  see that there appears to be no other way

Comment: @will interesting. The link tries to open `exp://192.168.1.2:19000`. Does that look right?

Comment: Consider VS Code as an alternative to Xcode. It's a much smaller program (you mentioned disk space), there are a number of plugins and a great community, and the Live Share plugin is great!